# Dead keys and non-determenistic "plain-mode"

Tags: windows, dead-keys

Many times when I want to type just an `, ~ or other dead key, it doesn't work when I press the dead key followed by space. It often works, but often not. I have been unable to find any rules for when this happens. I thus often press the dead key twice followed by backspace as that seems to work, but it's a lot of key presses. For ~ it is C+A+~+~+BACKSPACE...

Is other people experiencing this issue? And more importantly: found a way around it?

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Nope, never heard of that.

Comment: Depends on how often you use the characters I guess. When programming in D that is using ~ for array concatenation and ` for string literals, I experience it quite often. It doesn't seem related to a specific editor or version of Windows either.

Comment: Not to state the obvious but, have you tried a different keyboard.

Comment: You mean a different layout? This is not a new problem - I've experienced it on many different computers and keyboards over a long time. I have just gotten used to doing it the hard way, but my hands are getting tired, and I need to start thinking about minimizing key presses.

Answer (score 0):

This just sounds like a hardware issue.  I would try a different keyboard. Not because your current one is broken, but maybe because it doesn't fit your typing style.  I use to double type letters a lot on a desktop but not on a laptop. I realized it was because the laptop's keys use a far shorter stroke and provided a bit more tactile feedback. So I found a similiar keyboard: The HP Elite.